# Can I replace placeholder text in a rendered HTML page dynamically?

Tags: html, variables, dynamic, replace

I wish I could think of a better way to word my question, but basically here is what I want to do: in an HTML file, I would like to fill the body with a specific string multiple times. For example:

```
<div>
    This is some content. XXX
</div>
<div>
    This is some more content. XXX
</div>
<div>
    This is even more content. XXX
</div>
```

Then, I would like some script to go through the page, and replace every instance of the string (in this case XXX but it could be anything) with an incrementing number, so, like:

```
<div>
    This is some content. 001
</div>
<div>
    This is some more content. 002
</div>
<div>
    This is even more content. 003
</div>
```

This is a simple example of course, and you might be thinking well that's dumb, just type the numbers. But obviously this is simpler than what I'm intending to do, and right now what I'm building, the order of all the content has not been decided yet, so things could move up or down in their placement on the page, but I'd like all the numbers to be sequential in order of their appearance on the page.

So, final thoughts: I am super sure there's a way better way to do this than I'm even thinking of, methodology wise (i.e., make an XML table or something). I am definitely open to ANY suggestion on how to do this, but I am kind of an idiot so if your answer is "pff this would be super easy in Ruby just use Ruby", that's not gonna really get me where I need to be. Also if this has already been answered, it was hard to think of how to word the question to search for previous answers so I apologize in advance if I didn't find the pre-existing answer when I was searching.

Comment: I assume you have access to the files on the server? (You're not inputting this into some CMS type of interface, are you?)

Comment: That is correct, and a fair question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use PHP to achieve this. If you've had no experience with it, it does integrate with HTML easily. Basically you write your html as usual, but you name the file .php instead of .html. Then you insert php scripts as follows, for example: `<p>I can count to <?php nextNumber(); ?></p>`.

at the top of the page you should insert more script with a counter function:

```
<?php
$i = 1;
$places = 4;
function nextNumber() {
   GLOBAL $i, $places;
   print str_pad($i++,$places,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
?>
```

This may be better than CSS. It's not browser-dependant.

Change $places to the number of digits you'd like to have (for leading zeros)

Comment: Hmm... the leading zeros don't seem to be appearing:

http://iammichaeldavis.com/lego/rewards/keychain-reward-examples.php

Comment: So, I tried making the pad value a variable as well, so that the print function looked like `print str_pad($i++,$places,$pad,STR_PAD_LEFT);;`, but that didn't cut it either, so I tried `print str_pad($i++,4,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);` and that's got it. So apparently you can't use variables for the pad length, I guess.

@skibulk

Comment: Oh my bad - you can use a variable, I just didn't have it in the right scope. You see, by default functions don't have access to variables declared outside their brackets. That's why we use GLOBAL, so that the function can use variables that were declared outside of the function. So in this case "GLOBAL $i, $places;" should fix it.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily do this with CSS counters, [sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/jqyrb/):

### CSS

```
ul {
    counter-reset:list;
}
li:after {
    counter-increment:list;
    content: " (" counter(list) ")";
}
```

For some more advanced examples visit the [MDN documentation page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Counters).

Comment: Follow up question: is there any way to get the counter to display as a four digit number, like 0001 or 0304?

Comment: No, not exactly as you want it, but by adding `decimal-leading-zero` to the `counter` definition you can have it add a leading zero to numbers below 10, [see updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jqyrb/1/).

Comment: @Michael Davis - I've updated my answer to handle any number of leading zeros.

Comment: Last minute addition: [what you want is actually being designed by the W3C](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-counter-styles-3/#the-counter-style-rule). It is however currently an *Editor's Draft* still, and no browsers have support for it yet.

Comment: This was actually a great solution but the PHP solution is just a little closer to where I was trying to be. But thank you so much, this worked great and I've also learned that CSS has counters so this was a win win win for me :D